# Check if the image size is available and if not use 'full' image size

Tags: functions, theme-development, post-thumbnails

I have added an image size with code

```
add_image_size( 'medium_post_thumbnails', 87, 63, true);
```

By default WordPress has full/original image size.

I have a function where I use above image size 'medium_post_thumbnails',
but I also have old posts where the image has original size.

```
echo '<div class="medium-news border-bottom margin-top">' .'<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID). '">';
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'medium_post_thumbnails', array('class' => 'img-fluid')). '</a></div>';
```

What I want to do here is if the 'medium_post_thumbnails' image size is not present, the function should use 'full' image.

Comment: There are plugins that will regenerate your images - meaning they go through all your media library, grab the originals, and generate sizes based on your current settings, so all of your images would then have your new `medium_post_thumbnails` size available. That might be more efficient than writing a code workaround.

Comment: @WebElaine Its not possible to do that there are 50,000 images.
Thank you

Comment: Not sure why that wouldn't be possible, unless you're running out of disk space.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why something like this wouldnt work!

```
$med_post_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'medium_post_thumbnails', array('class' => 'img-fluid')). '</a></div>';
$full_post_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'FULL SIZE GOES HERE', array('class' => 'img-fluid')). '</a></div>';

if ($med_post_thumb == NULL) 
{
     echo $full_post_thumb;
} 
else
{
     echo $med_post_thumb;
}
```